# Как получить позицию массива при старте активити?

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

Есть ArrayList с кастомным классом `ArrayList<FoodDiaryClass> foodDiaryList`.

Есть проверка на наличие в одном из полей массива необходимых данных при старте активити:

```
for (FoodDiaryClass health : foodDiaryList) {
            if (health.getmHealth().contains("4")) {
                lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
```

К примеру, есть в массиве 5 позиций. Если хотя в одной их них условие будет выполняться, то в желтый цвет окрашиваются все имеющиеся строки.

**Задача - как окрасить в цвет только ту строку массива, для которой выполняется условие?** Собственно, не знаю, как получить позицию массива для ее проверки.

Comment: Это нужно делать в адаптере. Там же где Вы устанавливаете текст в строку списка - проверяйте условие и задавайте цвет. Цвет нужно задавать не `ListView` соответственно, а вью элемента списка.

Comment: Точно, как я не догадался. Спасибо!